# to get VS. getting

Tags: verbs, infinitives, gerunds

When I have to catch a train, I'm always worried that I'll miss it. So, I like getting/ **to get** to the station in plenty of time.

In grammar in use book, the bold part has been considered as correct answer. I am wondering why.

What is more, would you show me a more detailed explanation or another synonym for the following?-- I have some problem with especially using the preposition ***in*** along with plenty of time.

**in** plenty of time

My **specific** question is here:

Although there has been mentioned something an habit or something like that-- considering the adverb"always"--,so why don't we say getting?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are right. This sentence is not correct, in that it does't convey the right meaning.

Comment: *I like to reach the station plenty of time ahead*

Comment: Nima, I think you forgot to bold the section of your sentence you're asking about.

Comment: I am so sorry, as I forgot to bold it,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the use of *in* with *time*:

There's a couple of common expressions that use *in* with *time* (there's probably more than below):

*In time* - means before an understood deadline of some sort.  It differs from *on time* - *on time* means you arrived at the correct time - *in time* may mean you got there early.

("In time" can mean "when circumstances allow" or "eventually" - it will usually but not always start the sentence, or precede the subject-verb part of the sentence, i.e. *In time, we will conquer the enemy* or *If you keep working at it, in time you will succeed.)

*In plenty of time* - means with an ample amount of time left over.

For *in time* and *in plenty of time*, the point of time that you arrive is "within" or "inside of" the range of time you have to be at the destination, so "in" makes sense.

Let's say we are talking about a train - the train leaves at 5:00PM, and you learned of the train leaving then at 3:00PM.  You arrived at 4:45PM.  4:45PM is *in* the range of 3:00PM to 5:00PM.

Some others:

*In good time* - equivalent to *in plenty of time* (people racing one another comes to mind with this)

*In enough time* - when something is ready - *The cookies are baking.  In enough time we can eat them.*

*In no time* - means something has taken no time to happen, or a very short duration of time passed. - *I was driving recklessly and got to the station in no time.*

So...

> I like getting to the station in plenty of time.
>
> I like to get to the station in plenty of time.

These sound fine to me, but are something you'd hear in speech more than see in writing in my opinion.

---

Regarding the difference between *getting* and *to get*:

In my initial opinion as a native speaker, there is not a difference between them.  However, [this](http://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/gerund_or_infinitive_same_list.htm) says the following:

> Using a gerund *(-ing form)* suggests that you are referring to real activities or
> experiences. Using an infinitive *(to X)* suggests that you are talking about
> potential or possible activities or experiences.

So, since you are talking about a potential activity, *to get* is the right thing to use.

Comment: "to get to the station in plenty of time", doesn't that also mean "it took a plenty of time to reach the station"?

Comment: No.  If you explicitly state a duration, then it means that - i.e. "I got to the station in 3 hours." means it took you 3 hours to get to the station.  "I got to the station in plenty of time." means you arrived at the station on time.  See my edits, I clarified quite a bit and made some corrections after really thinking about this.