# To get vs in getting

Tags: word-choice, infinitive-vs-gerund

Which one is correct-

- He did not succeed *`to get`* the job though he tried his level best.
- He did not succeed *`in getting`* the job though he tried his level best.

Book says **second** one is correct.

Answer (score 1):

the verb succeed is followed by the preposition in and a gerund:

Someone does or does not **succeed in** doing something.

It's just that way if you want to be idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence below is correct as both past continuous and past perfect continuous tenses can be used to talk about actions or situations that were in progress at a certain point of time in the past. While the past continuous merely shows continuity, the past perfect continuous tense also puts an emphasis on the idea of duration. It is mainly used to indicate the duration of a past activity or state.

```
 He did not succeed in getting the job.
```

you can use this link [here](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/past-perfect-continuous-tense/) and explore more about usage of Tenses

Comment: Its not about tense. There was a question to select the correct sentence and as per book, only second(in getting) one is right.

Comment: Yes !  we do consider usage of words according . I get it where you are coming from please refer [this post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/44388/94582) For understanding usage of verbs . he has explained well . Hope this would help more